# Can I remove an object from the fetchedResultsController without deleting the object from the db?

Tags: iphone, database, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have been trying to remove an object from the tableView I am working with without deleting the object from the db, and I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried setting a predicate on the fetchedResultsController, to filter objects that have a BOOL set to a certain value. Then, when I change that value, I expect that I can get that object to stay in the db, but out of the fetchedResultsController because of the predicate, but alas, that isn't working.

How can I remove an object from my tableView's dataSource (the fetchedResultsController) without deleting it from the core data db completely?

Please help! I've been bashing my head against this for way too long

Comment: You're probably stuck on a detail, but the BOOL approach you describe should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always rolled my own table view data source when I need to weed out fetched results. `NSFetchedResultsController` objects are great when you want to show everything in your data base, but not so great when you want to weed out some of the data on the fly. I fetch the data, then iterate through the results array looking for the data I want to keep. The good objects get added to a new array, which becomes the basis of my table view data source.

The times I've implemented this, the data manipulation happens in a model object which hands off the array to the `UITableViewController` subclass that implements `UITabelViewDataSource` protocol methods. I suppose you could implement this as a subclass of `NSFetchedResultsController`, but I've never tried that approach.

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking all over for some sort of direction, and your answer gives me the idea that I need.